# Stripe Payment Intent - how to tell customer's country (and currency)?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a custom Stripe integration based on Stripe Payment Element JS library. In order to launch the Payment Element, I'm creating a Payment Intent on my server, using the Stripe PaymentIntents REST API. For this API, I need to specify the amount and currency in the input parameters.

The problem is, how do I choose the right currency for the PaymentIntent API, that would correspond to the customer's country (IP address)?

Both Stripe Prebuilt Checkout and the Payment Element JS UI detect and display the customer's country in their own UI, but there seems no way to extract it. Neither there is a Stripe backend API for that.

I just don't get it, how this whole thing is supposed to work, because I believe knowing the country (and therefore the currency) is essential for creating any payment intent. Am I missing something, how do you guys do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe's "JS UI" doesn't determine currency and neither does Checkout in most cases. That's why there's no API for it or feature.

Usually, you, as a business, know what currency you sell your product in. For example if you navigate on the US version of Amazon, prices are in USD and in France they are in EUR.

If you want to support multiple currencies on your website, you often have a default currency and then customers can change it in their settings. I see this on many websites like airbnb and such in the bottom right corner.

The way to determine the right default depends a lot on your preference and business model. Some websites will assume a default currency always of USD for example. Others will try to guess based on your IP address or your browser's locale. This is something Stripe doesn't do for you, you have to build this yourself and then create the underlying PaymentIntent in the currency of your choice. You could also just ask your customer upfront too.

It is true that with multi-currency Prices, Checkout does support detecting the currency on load. The idea is that you add a Price with currency options in USD, EUR and GBP and then on Checkout page load Stripe can determine the customer's most likely currency based on their IP address for example and "pin" that Checkout Session to the right one. The customer can't control or change it though.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that multi-currency experience is what I had in mind, similar to how it works in Stripe Prebuilt Checkout. I could have multi-currency prices and I would like my store to chose the right currency for the country the customer is in. This is also related to taxes. I'd like to use tax-inclusive prices, to avoid calculating taxes in advance - similar to multi-currency price tiers in Apple's App Store. For example, in the App Store, the price in EUR is slightly higher, in FX equivalent, than the price in USD in the same price tier, to cover for the European VAT.

Comment: So you are basically saying this is something impossible to build? So how do I let the customer know how much will be actually charged and in what currency, before the checkout is complete?

Comment: I never said it was impossible, I even explained how to build this with various ways: Ask the customer, detect based on their IP, offer a list of currencies available, etc. This is 100% doable, just you have to build this yourself as a developer. It's not something Stripe offers directly beyond giving you control of this in their API.

Comment: The problem is that Stripe will calculate taxes based on the customer’s IP address and payment method’s billing address but only *AFTER* the checkout is complete. Therefore, if the price is tax-exclusive, the customer will pay more than they expected. Tax-inclusive prices per country could work around this, but if the customer chooses a country with no tax, I will receive less revenue after Stripe establishes the real country. What is the most reasonable way to work around this problem?

Comment: Stripe doesn't calculate tax for you unless you use Checkout or Invoicing, in which case they control it all and you don't have to worry about selecting the right currency. At this point you would be better off talking to Stripe's support team directly about your exact requirements, what products you use, etc.: https://support.stripe.com/contact